# Sort items via Weight module

Tags: php, drupal, sorting, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a custom module and installed [Weight](http://drupal.org/project/weight) module. And i want, sort items with weight on page. But i don't know how can i do this?

My module:
http://pastebin.com/DuCdFdH6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you use the module as is (with its UI), or you use the private functions that the module [internally uses](http://drupalcode.org/project/weight.git/blob/aec327c10a119808a2f5a0cd47b18ddd8e235506:/weight.module#l420).

Namely:

```
_weight_set_weight($node)
_weight_get_weight($node)
_weight_get_settings($type = NULL)
_weight_get_types()
_weight_get_options($range)
_weight_set_defaults($default, $type)
```

But clearly, as the module is defined, it expects you to use the views defined, and more generally its UI.

If you don't know how to use it, refer to [its documentation](http://drupal.org/node/307797).